# Load iframe tag (video) from html string into web view using Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, iframe, swift3

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4jTl.png)

It shows GRAY frame, but it has only black borders...no video shown!
Hint: load function only accepts Data type, not String...but after converting, nothing happands!

```
@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

func callWS(){
    let  url = URL(string: "endpoint url")

    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)


    let task = session.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: {

        (data, response, error) in

        if error != nil
        {
            print("Error")
        }
        else
        {
            if let content = data
            {
                do {
                    let myJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content) as? [String:Any]

                    let text:String = myJSON?["text"] as! String

                    let textData:Data = text.data(using: .utf8)!

                    //self.webView.loadHTMLString(text, baseURL: nil) no frame
                    self.webView.load(textData, mimeType: "text/html", textEncodingName: "utf8", baseURL: NSURL() as URL)
                }
                catch {}
            }
        }
    })

    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Where do you think the problem lies? At the line `let text:String = myJSON?["text"] as! String`, what is the value of `text`? Is it valid html? `.loadHTMLString()` should work fine if the string is valid html.

Comment: At top of my question, there is image...it shows emulators screen.

self.test.load(text.data(using: .utf8)!, mimeType: "text/html", textEncodingName: "UTF-8", baseURL: NSURL() as URL)

//text is String from json, in string is html...it is valid html, working on Android...

Comment: webViewText.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://.", htmlText, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);

//This is working on android...first argument is baseURL...how to set it in Swift? Maybe, there is error...

Comment: You are getting JSON data from your "endpoint url", yes? And are you parsing that JSON data to get a ***html string*** to load into the web view? Or are you pulling a new ***URL*** from the JSON data, and you want to go to that URL in your web view?

Comment: Parsing JSON data to get a html string to load into the web view. I'm only using one parameter from json object, it has html string code in it.

Comment: OK - So... I ask again: What is the value of `text`? Is it valid HTML?

Comment: @DonMag Yes, it's valid.

"text": "<p>adassa dasdas dsadas .<\/p>\r\n<p>as a “ dsds. a!” a a<span style=\"color: #0000ff;\"><strong><a href=\"https://www.unroadsafetyweek.org/en/home\" target=\"_blank\" style=\"color: #0000ff;\">a sigurnost<\/a>,<\/strong> <\/span>a  a dsa.<\/p>\r\n<p><\/p>\r\n<p><iframe width=\"560\" height=\"314\" src=\"//www.youtube.com/embed/3JcmQONgXJM\" allowfullscreen=\"allowfullscreen\"><\/iframe><\/p>\r\n<p><\/p>\r\n<p><iframe width=\"560\" height=\"314\" src=\"//www.youtube.com/embed/3JcmQONgXJM\" allowfullscreen=\"allowfullscreen\"><\/iframe><\/p>"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use `.loadHTMLString()`. Change your code to:

```
    let myJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content) as? [String:Any]

    let text:String = myJSON?["text"] as! String

    self.webView.loadHTMLString(text, baseURL: URL(string: "https://"))
```

You *may* also have to first replace the extra escape chars. Without your actual call to get the JSON data, I can't replicate it exactly for testing - but I had to remove them to get the HTML format to be correct.

So, if you end up with tags being shown instead of being parsed as tags:

```
adassa dasdas dsadas .<\/p>
```

that means the JSON string actually has invalid characters, so you probably want to do it like this:

```
    let myJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content) as? [String:Any]

    let text:String = myJSON?["text"] as! String

    // remove the extra "\" escape chars
    let cleanedText = text.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\/", with: "/")

    self.webView.loadHTMLString(cleanedText, baseURL: URL(string: "https://"))
```

Comment: base url - cannot convert String to expected argument URL? It's swift 3...i watch examples, not working with baseURL: nil, not working with replacingOccurrences...

Comment: Sorry, I re-typed instead of copy/paste and forgot the URL() format.